# Tagging code for refactoring using attributes in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, attributes

I'm currently in the process of converting a JavaScript SharePoint application into a WPF version of the same thing written in C#. The JavaScript does a lot of both UI and data manipulation, so as part of the exercise, I'm going to want to move a lot of methods around to better fit the MVVM approach that WPF favours.

What I'd LIKE to do if flag every class I bring across with `[MVVMType("Model")]` or `[MVVMType("ViewModel")]`, and then flag methods with attributes like `[MVVMTarget("ViewModel")]`. The idea would be to generate a warning (probably using the `Obsolete` attribute on a method the attribute would run) when an `MVVMTarget` attribute value conflicts with the `MVVMType` attribute of the containing class, or if no attribute was present.

The issue is, whilst I'm aware of how to add attributes to classes/methods, I'm not aware of how to look at the context of an attribute-bearer to do this kind of thing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Attributes Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: This helps, but not quite clear from it how to do attribute validation from within an attribute (e.g. from an attribute on a method, get the attributes of the object it is attached to) - or isn't that how it works? So rather than starting from an outside in approach, I'd like to work from inside to outside. At least if it's possible.